# Need help with Excel macro to organize a messed up survey

Tags: excel, vbscript, survey

I have been trying to write a macro (in steps) to organize the results of a very poorly designed survey, but I am having very little luck.

Here is a sample of what I have:

[image]

Here is a sample of what I need:

[image]

I am running into several problems, one of which is that not all of the 15 questions on the survey had to be answered which makes looping through the results in a smooth fashion difficult.

An even bigger problem (tied to the previous issue) is that 3 of the 15 questions on the survey were "Select All That Apply" type questions, and every selection was recorded as a separate answer, but with the same number.  For example question 10 had 11 possible selections which a user could choose as many or as few of as they wanted.  If they selected the 1st and 3th options of question 10 the result would look like rows 3 and 4 of my `What I have` sample.

My `What I need` sample shows that I need all the questions in columns and all the respondent numbers in their own row, with the long answers from a respondent under their respective number.

The `ID` column from the `What I have` sample is not needed in the final product, but I have left it in the results for now thinking it might somehow help sort this mess out.

**I am wondering if I should just go back to the person who gave this to me and tell them I'm sorry but I cannot do anything with this since it is so messed up.  If you think it is possible to fix these survey results please give me some pointers (be detailed, I don't have much experience with VB Script).**

Any other comments, thoughts, or suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: This is not messed up, it is a fairly standard approach to a survey. It would be very easy to analyse in a database or you can use SQL in Excel. What approach do you fancy?

Comment: @Remou I have a lot more SQL experience than I do VB Script (MySQL).  I would like to leave it in Excel (and use SQL as you suggested) if possible, but if you think putting it in a database first would be easier I will go that route.

Comment: Okay, I will get back to you, if someone else does not beat me to it :)

Comment: @Remou thanks! I'll try to work with this in an Access database in the mean time... Maybe I'll get lucky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have years of experience with VBA in Excel and Access 2003 and 2010, and I can tell you this would not be fun to process in Excel; based on the structure of the survey results, I would highly recommend importing this into Access (if you have it) and running SQL queries to slice and dice the data.  It's really in the format of a database table, it even has a primary key (ID).

Comment: It would not be all that bad. You can use a Jet connection, ADO and SQL in Excel without too much difficulty.

Comment: Well it wouldn't be that bad, but I figure in Access he could write a few quick SQL queries and/or create a nice report on the survey.

Comment: I have imported this in to an Access database and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I would import that into a database then use a simple query or two to generate what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start in Excel VBA, in Access this is quite a simple query.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
''you want, but it is very convenient for notes
''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
''can be used.
''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

''Late binding, so no reference is needed
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


cn.Open strCon

''Note that strings are case-sensitive
strSQL = "Transform First(a.Answer) As Ans " _
       & "SELECT a.Respondent " _
       & "FROM [Sheet2$] As b " _
       & "LEFT JOIN " _
       & "(SELECT ID,Val(Question & '.' & " _
       & "IIf(Mid(Answer,5,8)='Checkbox', Mid(Answer,1,1),1)) As Qstn, " _
       & "Respondent,Answer " _
       & "FROM [Sheet1$]) As a " _
       & "ON a.[Qstn]=b.[Question] " _
       & "GROUP BY a.Respondent " _
       & "PIVOT b.question"


rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

''Pick a suitable empty worksheet for the results
For i = 0 To rs.fields.Count - 1
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.fields(i).Name
Next

Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

''Tidy up
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

This is based on having a table on sheet2, like so:

```
Question
1.1
2.1
3.1
4.1
5.1
6.1
7.1
8.1
9.1
9.2
9.3
9.4
10.1
10.2
10.3
10.4
11.1
11.1
11.1
11.1
11.1
<...>
```

Comment: I appreciate all the effort you are putting into this, but after having imported the survey results to Access I think a few queries will have everything sorted out.  I have mostly dealt with MySQL so I am a bit unfamiliar with the SQL Server syntax used in Access, but I'm working through it.

Comment: Well, like I said, it is standard database format. You can grab the sql statement above, it will run in Access with very little modification, just make sure to add a question table, like the one illustrated above, and use the table names in place of the sheet names.